# Need help with Windows Speech Recognition script to compound a string

Tags: string, windows-vista, speech-recognition, spaces

The command below for Windows Speech Recognition forces the speech recognition engine to use literal text (""all seventy six people paid five dollars") instead of the default ("all 76 people paid $5").

I'm trying to adapt this command to remove the spaces between words so that I could program using speech by saying things like:

```
"Security Manager"
-> "Security Manager"
"Compound That"
-> "SecurityManager"
```

The way I think this could work is by using a regex to remove the spaces between the selected text. So, in the following code:

```
  <command priority="5">
    <listenFor>literal that</listenFor>
    <emulateRecognition>select that</emulateRecognition>
    <sendKeys>{250 WAIT}{{CTRL}}c{250 WAIT}</sendKeys>
      <!-- Works by first inserting the word " literal " before each word
           example "all 76 people paid $5"
           is emulated as "literal all literal 76 literal people literal paid literal $5"
           which produces the result "all seventy six people paid five dollars"

           EmulateRecognition can fail if the text contains improper formatting or nonsense words
           (which can easily happen if only part of a word in the document is included in the text selection).
           When the failure can be handled by "On Error Resume Next", such as EmulateRecognition("literal s")
           or EmulateRecognition("multiple  spaces"), we restore the original text and show feedback message.
           Unfortunately, some failures, such as EmulateRecognition("nonsens"), cause macros to immediately
           halt. This is why "replace that with " is used. Either it succeeds, or it fails non-destructively
           (before any text is deleted). Unfortunately, this can be confusing for the user because the macro
           can fail without doing anything visible to the user (no changes to the text, and no SetTextFeedback.)
      -->
    <script language="VBScript">
      <![CDATA[
      that = Application.clipboardData.GetData("text")
      Set regEx = New RegExp
      regEx.Pattern = "[^\s\w,;:]"
      If regEx.Test(that) Then
        Application.SetTextFeedback("Try again without any punctuation selected")
      Else
        regEx.Pattern = "(\s) *(\S)"
        regEx.Global = True
        that = regEx.Replace(" " & that, "$1literal $2")
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EmulateRecognition("replace that with" & that)
        If 0 <> Err.Number Then
          Application.SetTextFeedback("Try again with only the digits selected")
        End If
      End If
    ]]>
    </script>
  </command>
```

instead of writing this:

```
        regEx.Pattern = "(\s) *(\S)"
        regEx.Global = True
        that = regEx.Replace(" " & that, "$1literal $2")
```

I think it would need to use some other regex pattern that extracts whitespace between words and pushes the words together in the new output.

I'm not sure how to do that. Would appreciate if anyone has a suggestion.

Comment: I fear you will have more luck with this question on Stackoverflow, but no worries it will probably be transferred soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the 'literal' command, you could also use the 'nospace' command to suppress spaces between words.  See the [examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/tsfaware/archive/2008/08/26/inline-dictation-commands.aspx) on my blog.